# importing the Django's model classes - Python

Tags: python, django

I have looked at similar questions in stackoverflow before asking this question, and none of them could help me solve the problem.

I have a `Django` project called `testrun`.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 pribeiro  Users  196608 Dec  5 21:38 db.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x  20 pribeiro  Users     680 Dec 19 16:14 graphs
-rw-r--r--   1 pribeiro  Users     250 Dec  4 20:11 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x   8 pribeiro  Users     272 Dec 12 21:57 parser
drwxr-xr-x  10 pribeiro  Users     340 Dec 23 09:56 testrun
```

I have an app called `graphs`, inside `testrun` (`graphs` has been added to `testrun/settings.py` as an `INSTALLED_APPS`):

```
-rw-r--r--  1 pribeiro  Users     0 Dec  4 23:05 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 pribeiro  Users   739 Dec  5 21:45 admin.py
drwxr-xr-x  7 pribeiro  Users   238 Dec 19 09:07 migrations
-rw-r--r--  1 pribeiro  Users  3945 Dec 19 09:07 models.py
-rw-r--r--  1 pribeiro  Users  5057 Dec 19 16:14 parser.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 pribeiro  Users    68 Dec 12 18:33 static
drwxr-xr-x  3 pribeiro  Users   102 Dec  5 22:31 staticfiles
drwxr-xr-x  3 pribeiro  Users   102 Dec  5 22:32 templates
-rw-r--r--  1 pribeiro  Users   343 Dec 19 15:22 test_parser.py
-rw-r--r--  1 pribeiro  Users    60 Dec  4 23:05 tests.py
-rw-r--r--  1 pribeiro  Users   149 Dec 12 18:22 urls.py
-rw-r--r--  1 pribeiro  Users   287 Dec 12 18:29 views.py
```

I tried to run `python manage.py shell` and then:

```
>>> from testrun.graphs.models import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named graphs.models
```

Therefore, in `graphs\parser.py` I tried to import the classed present in `models.py` because I will need them when I parse a `.json` file that represents the classes in `models.py`:

```
from graphs.models import *

class Parser:
   def __init__(self, filename=''): 
       self.api_test = APITest()
```

and `APITest` is a class in `models.py`:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

class APITest(models.Model):
    #... def goes here
```

When I execute `graphs\parser.py` I get:

```
$ python parser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from graphs.models import *
ImportError: No module named graphs.models
```

Could someone please explain why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
python manage.py shell

from graphs.models import *
```

and add 
    from .models import APITest

to parser.py and run 
    python manage.py shell

```
from graphs.parser import Parser
```

In order to manage dependencies in Django it is best to use python virtualenv.

If you just want to run some logic from Django from command line, try using Writing custom django-admin commands. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

In your case if you want to have a script my_parser.py you would place it in graphs/management/commands/ folder and you can run it as python manage my_parser.

The code of my_parser would look something like this

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from .models import APITest

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<arg1 arg2...>'
    help = 'Help line ...'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        ... # You code comes here
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one doesn't work because you do:

```
from testrun.graphs.models import *
```

but it should be :

```
from graphs.models import *
```

because your pythonpath is already pointing to the `testrun` project directory. The first import will look in the `testrun/testrun/` directory, i guess that's not what you want.

The second one doesn't work because i assume you execute the file from the `graphs` directory. If you execute the file from there, the import won't work, because the import is assuming the python path is pointing to the `testrun` project root directory.

Comment: did you try `from graphs.models import *` ...?

Comment: $ python graphs/parser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graphs/parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from graphs.models import *
ImportError: No module named graphs.models

Comment: when working in a django project, you better not execute the files seperately, you can better run `./manage.py shell` and then import and call the stuff you want.